# PHP/Mysql how to join another table to a match against search query

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm creating this cool website, but getting stuck where I want to join another table to a match against search query. I wrote this code:

```
$sql = "SELECT *, MATCH(ppa, specialization)".
" AGAINST('$search_parameter' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ".
"AS score FROM ppa JOIN organizations o ".
"ON o.id = ppa.id WHERE MATCH(ppa, specialization) ".
"AGAINST('$search_parameter' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND".
" location = '$location' ORDER BY score DESC ";"
```

And it gives me this error: Column 'location' in where clause is ambiguous

```
SELECT *,
       MATCH(ppa, specialization) AGAINST('computer science' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score
FROM ppa
JOIN organizations o ON o.id = ppa.id
WHERE MATCH(ppa, specialization) AGAINST('computer science' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  AND LOCATION = 'London'
ORDER BY score DESC.
```

How can I resolve this error

Comment: Have you in the both tables you join attribute named LOCATION?

Answer (score 0):

You have a `location` column in both tables. MySQL cannot decide which one to use in the query, hence it raises an error message. Indicate from which table you want to use the `location` field by adding table name to the field reference (use the appropriate table):

```
...
AND ppa.LOCATION = 'London'
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is giving error because `location` field is available in both the tables (in ppa and in organizations). You haven't mention in `where` clause that `location` filed in `location = '$location'` query belongs to which table.

You can replace `location` in `location = '$location'` by `ppa.location` or `o.location` to make it correct.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT ppa.*,
       MATCH(ppa.ppa, ppa.specialization) AGAINST('computer science' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score
FROM ppa as ppa
JOIN organizations o ON o.id = ppa.id
WHERE MATCH(ppa.ppa, ppa.specialization) AGAINST('computer science' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  AND LOCATION = 'London'
ORDER BY score DESC.